# Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. More than one file was found with OS independent path

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I've got this error on my project. Is is based on firebase-messaging API's. Before putting the:

```
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+' 
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+' 
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
```

It was working.

```
dependencies
{
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please add the following depenecy in your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

> Your build.gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

Please also make sure you have in your top level (Project) `build.gradle` file the following Google Services plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```